# TensorFlow C library on raspberry

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm trying to make the tensorflow c library work on raspberry pi3 B+ using the official guide:
[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c)

when I try to compile with gcc the .c file, the result is:

//usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't know now if this can work on raspberry

Comment: I am having the same problem..I need the C library for ARM but when I look to the available options in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c I cannot find anything for ARM. Did you manage it to work?

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked says it's supported on **Linux, 64-bit, x86.** The Raspberry Pi has an ARM processor, so that library won't work at all.

Did you look at [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian)? In addition to Raspbian images, it has instructions for cross-compiling from source.

Comment: as I feared, I need to use the c library, so I need to cross-compiling it. Thanks